# Why does Vue ignore css rule?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following html code

```
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">        
        <div>
            1. This is 1st line

            2. This is 2nd line

            3. This is 3rd line
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="white-space: pre-line;">
            1. This is 1st line

            2. This is 2nd line

            3. This is 3rd line
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Which will result in

```
1. This is 1st line 2. This is 2nd line 3. This is 3rd line


1. This is 1st line

2. This is 2nd line

3. This is 3rd line
```

However, when I mount a Vue instance onto my main div, this is the result I get

```
1. This is 1st line 2. This is 2nd line 3. This is 3rd line

1. This is 1st line 2. This is 2nd line 3. This is 3rd line
```

The code for Vue instance in the script.js file is as follow

```js
const test = Vue.createApp({

}).mount("#main")
```

Why did my white-space style get ignored completely?

Comment: This is probably a matter of how the compiler takes the various pieces of HTML and glues them together. `pre-line` is taking the new line into account but it's probably not exactly the same between the behavior of the browser and what JS is doing with it. Still, it quite a minor problem here, since you could fix it by adding a `<br />` or even wrapping your lines into other parents. Not a big deal worth spending much time on IMO. TLDR: it's not ignored, just the compiler doing it's own stuff VS browser's default behavior.

Comment: @tony19 https://codepen.io/NepNepFFXIV/pen/oNEWLgz?editors=1111

Answer (score 2):

The Vue compiler collapses whitespace by default, so the newlines in your original code gets collapsed (extraneous whitespace is removed) to produce more efficient compiled output.

### Option 1: App config to disable whitespace-condense

You can disable this *globally* in your example with [`app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-compileroptions) set to `'preserve'`:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve'
app.mount("#main")
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oNEWWaX?editors=1010)

Or disable it per component:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  compilerOptions: {
    whitespace: 'preserve'
  }
})
app.mount("#main")
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wvydqmB?editors=1010)

**Note:** `app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace` is only respected when using the full build. Otherwise, you'd have to set the option through build flags.

### Option 2: Build flag to disable whitespace-condense

You can configure `@vue/compiler-sfc` to disable whitespace-condense in this Vite config:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          whitespace: 'preserve', 
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

[demo 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-preserve-whitespace-in-templates?file=vite.config.js)

### Option 3: Use `<br>` where new-line is needed

Alternatively, you could explicitly add `<br>` tags where needed, which would keep the originally intended optimization while implementing the desired spacing:

```html
<div>
  1. This is 1st line<br>

  2. This is 2nd line<br>

  3. This is 3rd line<br>
</div>
```